# Bash Login prompt disappeared

Tags: bash, authentication

I recently made changes to my /etc/profile, and afterwards when I open a new tab in iTerm or Terminal I don't get a prompt. I tried reverting the changes in /etc/profile to the way I thought they were before - using Vim's undo - but I still don't get a login prompt, I just get a blank screen with a blinking cursor in the top left corner. I tried logging in as a different user, and the other user has the same problem, so I think the error is in the global bash login. /etc/motd doesn't run, but I'm not sure about the other files. Normally I would restart the computer but I have one shell that works and I'm hesitant to lose it by restarting the computer. Is there anywhere where an error would be logged? Thanks for your help,
Kevin

Here's my /etc/profile:

```
#put this in to try and debug, but does not show on the screen
echo "hello"

export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
[ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi

fortune
```

Comment: What's in your `/etc/profile` currently?

Comment: It's possible that you caused some kind of infinite loop. When you open a new tab, what processes are shown in ps? What is the cpu usage like?

Comment: CPU usage is about 10-20%. I've edited the question to show my /etc/profile.

Comment: Does `ps` show any additional processes? E.g. that /usr/libexec/path_helper thing?

Comment: There are only about 8-9 processes running when I type `ps aux`

Comment: 1. Do you see a new bash process when you open a new tab 2. If you do see a new bash process, try `ps faux` - does it have any child processes?

Comment: Bash has nothing to do with the login prompt. Do you mean the shell command-line prompt? Also, what does `path_helper` do and what does its output look like? Is `/etc/bashrc` sourcing `/etc/profile` thus creating a loop? When Bash is started as a non-login interactive shell, `/etc/profile` is not used. How are you starting the shell?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Since opening a new terminal does not normally issue a login prompt, I assumed that the OP is talking about the shell prompt. I, too, think that we are dealing with a `source` loop or a child process that does not terminate...

Comment: Hey, as it turns out I accidentally closed the one functioning window, so I tried restarting the computer and that fixed the problem. Thanks for the help, Kevin

Comment: @Kevin: In that case you should close (not delete) this question to remove it from the active question list.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain how to close a question?

Comment: @Kevin: I believe that there should be a 'close' link under your question - right under the tags.

Comment: All I have is link | delete | edit | flag. Maybe it has to do with the number of points that I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally closed the window, and after I did I tried restarting the computer. When I logged back in the prompt displayed properly. Thanks for the help in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Since when you open a new terminal it remains open, it seems that bash is still running but:

- It does not show a prompt because you broke `$PS1`. In that case you might be still able to enter commands. `export PS1='$ '` would be a good start in that case.

or

- It is still doing something from `/etc/profile`. Either it's waiting for another process, or it has entered some kind of infinite loop - like the one caused by a shell file `source` loop.

Since you have a working terminal, you should check the running processes in `ps` before and after you start a new shell, to get an idea on what's going on.